# what is the difference between - I make it to go and I make it go?

Tags: complementation, bare-infinitives, to-infinitive, causatives

What is the difference between sentences like these:

> I make it to go.
>   I make it go.

or

> You make me to cry.
>   You make me cry.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Have you considered using your first best friend (Google) to reach an answer?

Answer (score 4):

In English, modal verbs such as *CAN, WILL*, the verbs *MAKE, LET* and also verbs of perception, for example *SEE, FEEL* or *HEAR* take verbs in the plain form. These verbs appear without the word *to*. For this reason:

- *You make me to cry (ungrammatical)

... is badly formed. It's ungrammatical. We need the plain form of *CRY* without the word *to*:

- You make me cry.

Some verbs in English can take another verb either in the plain form or with a *to*-infinitive. One example is the verb *HELP*:

- He helped me to carry the piano.
- He helped me carry the piano.

Comment: Is there any difference between "me to carry the piano and " me carry the piano?

Comment: @tadek No, I don't think so :)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly ditto Aracaria.

I'd add that "to " can be used to describe a state of being, as opposed to an individual action. So you can say, for example, "I live to serve", i.e. my purpose in life is to serve. Or, "I was born to love you" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNhhAEupU4g)

If you were describing, say, the creation of a robot that is designed to act sad, the robot might say to its inventor, "You made me to cry." That's the closest I can think of to a meaningful variation of your example sentence.