# Let us not to forget or Let us not forget?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

Which one of the following sentences is **grammatically** correct?

> 1. Let us not forget something.
> 2. Let us not to forget something.

It is different from the question: [what is the difference between - I make it to go and I make it go?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/what-is-the-difference-between-i-make-it-to-go-and-i-make-it-go)

since this question I have asked wants to know whether the word "to" is needed after the verb and object "let us" and in the **negative form** "not forget."

Comment: Does "have a nice time" relate to the question, or is that meant to be a greeting? Also, in general, [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) are welcome, like your thoughts on the matter, why you want to say this, and what you _think_ you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 is correct, the "to" is not called for.  If you were trying to say not to forget an action that needed performed, the "to" would then be called for, but as:  "Let us not forget to do something."  "to forget" is an infinitive and not the correct form for your sentence #2 though.